# Property 'translate' does not exist on type 'LogComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to do a function to change language on my page, but I am getting this error:

Property 'translate' does not exist on type 'LogComponent'

```
export class LogComponent {
      langs: any;
      constructor( translate: TranslateService ){    
        this.langs = translate.getLangs();

      }

      langSelect(lang: string): void {
        this.translate.use(lang);
      }

    }
```

and my html:

```
<select #langSelected (change)="langSelect(langSelected)">
  <option *ngFor="let l of langs" [value]="l">{{ l }}</option>
</select>
```

And this is not working... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`translate` doesn't exist, because you never defined it as a variable. Try changing the line from

```
constructor( translate: TranslateService ){
```

to

```
constructor( private translate: TranslateService ){
```

Putting `public`, `private`, `protected`, etc. in the constructor definition is shorthand for defining it as a class variable, like this:

```
export class LogComponent {
  private translate: TranslateService;

  constructor( translate: TranslateService ){    
    this.translate = translate;
  }
}
```